# SQL Server view - bad naming convention?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @TableName AS VARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @ViewCheck as CURSOR;

SET @ViewCheck = CURSOR FOR
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'V_WFC%'

OPEN @ViewCheck

FETCH NEXT FROM @ViewCheck INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

Set @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ' + @TableName 

PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)

FETCH NEXT FROM @ViewCheck INTO @TableName;
END

CLOSE @ViewCheck
```

I have a cursor that runs through all SQL views in a particular schema to sanity check that they continue to function, some are tied to reporting and some used as an application data source in ProSolution.

One of these views is named **UnmarkedRegister(Today)** the brackets used to differentiate it from a from a similar view, this one is used within an application to drive display data.

While the query runs as expected, returning the correct data  - the cursor returns an error

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'V_WFC_UnmarkedRegister'

and I'm wondering why the bracketed section is omitted in the EXEC(SQL) section of the cursor?

Comment: This is really unlikely to burn you unless you've got some pretty weird object names, but if you're actually looking for views whose names start with "V_WFC", then use `LIKE 'V[_]WFC%'` instead. The square brackets instruct `LIKE` to interpret the underscore as a literal character; otherwise it's a wildcard that matches any single character. So for instance, a view called `VXWFC_UnmarkedRegister` would satisfy your original `LIKE` expression.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`quotename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
Set @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you.

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [V_WFC_UnmarkedRegister(Today)]
(0 rows affected)

Comment: it may be worth [explaining what this does](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), and why it fails without quotename: the brackets form part of the syntax in t-sql for a UDF call. without quoting square brackets, t-sql's tokenizer separates it into the identifier `V_WFC_UnmarkedRegister` and the argument `Today`. before it evaluates this nonexistent argument, it looks up the identifier which is not in the schema. next it would complain that there is no schema prefix which is required for a function call, but that's yet another story.

Answer (score 5):

I truly detest cursors and there is no need for a cursor here at all. You can greatly simplify this code in a couple of ways. First I am using sys.views instead of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. And then I am using sql to build a dynamic sql string instead of a cursor. Look how simple this can be.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = '';

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select top 10 * from ' + QUOTENAME(v.name) + '; select ''('' + convert(varchar(2), @@ROWCOUNT) + '' rows affected'';'
from sys.views v
where v.name LIKE 'V_WFC%'

print @SQL
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: If you have any views outside the `dbo` schema, you would need to add a join to `sys.schemas s on v.schema_id = s.schema_id` in the `from` clause and a `QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' +` to the `select` clause.

Comment: @tarheel agreed. But since the OP was only looking at the default schema I didn't see the need to extend it.

Comment: Because of the constraints of the application that "owns" the database, all views are stored within a separate reporting database and won't fall outside of that schema, but that's a fair point.

Comment: I don't mind cursors, I liked your offering but the benefit of the cursor in this case is the format of the output.  

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [V_WFC_ApplicationOffering]
(10 rows affected)

Comment: Cursors are the spawn of the devil. They are so often used a crutch when it is just isn't needed. You can accomplish what you want with row count quite easily. See my edit. The real issue with cursors is they are just so damn slow. For a small set like views it may not be a big deal. I just despise them vehemently and find ways to eradicate them. They have their place but few and far between. :)

Comment: I pretty much detest cursors as well, but this is a fine use-case for them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't disagree I was demonstrating a way to avoid them even in a case like this.

Answer (score 3):

Because brackets usually identify a function call

changing this line:

```
Set @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ' + @TableName
```

to this should fix it:

```
Set @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [' + @TableName + ']'
```

Comment: This works fine, until you have a view with a `]` in it's name. :) Of course, using special characters in an object's name is never a good idea, but the OP already had a view with a parenthesis in it, so, I wouldn't suggest that *assuming* they don't have a view with a `]`in it's name is safe either. :)

Comment: This will cover most/all special characters, except the [ or ], dont think it will let you use those in a table name.  I just tried creating a table with one of those and it did not allow me to use it.

Comment: Using QUOTENAME will fix all cases though. :)

Comment: @Brad you can, you have to double up the `]`, like you would a `'` in a literal string. For example: `CREATE TABLE [[IHaveBrackets!!!]]] (ID int);`. If you then query `sys.tables`: `SELECT [name]
FROM sys.tables
WHERE [name] LIKE '%IHaveB%';` you'll see the table was created with the name `'[IHaveBrackets!!!]'`. :)

Comment: @Larnu cool, good to know, nothing I would do or should ever be done, but good to know in case I come across it thanks!

Comment: We have two "unmarked register" views - one for the current academic year and one specifically for "Today", hence the brackets. If it weren't for the need to have a smaller dataset, I would have just filtered the original view at run time.

Comment: You can use underscores and add numbers, like TableName  and TableName2017  Or TableName_2017  better than using special characters

Comment: Sure those are better but not always what people run into. Some people actually do stupid things to names like "This is a [table] (Really)". I have seen stupid stuff like that. In the real world these terrible decisions still have to be dealt with.